# Convert UTF-8 accents in ASCII

Tags: php

I saw there are different discussion on this subject and I did find some solutions, but I still can't fix the accent problem.

I have a text in Italian, we have some letters with accents (`à`, `è`, `é`, `ì`, `ò` and `ù`), this text gets sent in a file over to another website and this has to be in `ASCII` format, this is what I'm currently doing:

```
$res_to_write = "Non c'è più l'oblò, è lì o là?" //DEMO TEXT
$resfile = iconv("UTF-8", "US-ASCII//TRANSLIT", $res_to_write);
```

The result is in ASCII, which is good but it gets converted to:

`Non c'e piu l'oblo, e li o la?`

Which is completely wrong in Italian.

Do I have to make a replace of every accent like `è` => `e'` (single quote) so at least looks ok or there is another solution to this?

Comment: The site supports only *ASCII*? Then it's fundamentally incompatible with Italian. Sure you can't at least use ISO-8859-1?

Comment: @deceze the site is Swiss so they have multiple languages (Italian, Franch, English and German) and for some reason I'm not aware of they want is plain ASCII.

Comment: I believe iconv with //TRANSLIT option only converts characters into different characters, it does not convert "one character into most visibly-similar character set", which is what you want (`è => e'`). But even converting it like you proposed wouldn't make it right.

Comment: We are in 2018 and we still have different Char Codes this makes me go nuts, cant' we invent a global one and make it approve at IEEE??

Comment: We have. It's called Unicode, and its most prevalent and de-facto standard incarnation is UTF-8. That doesn't mean all other encodings have been abolished (sadly) or that everyone is on board with Unicode yet (sadly).

Comment: So no solution to this apparently... :(

Answer (score 0):

As of now I don't have other solutions other than replace it with an apostrophe:

```
$res_to_write = "Non c'è più l'oblò, è lì o là?" //DEMO TEXT
$res_to_write = str_replace(['à', "è", "é", "ì", "ò", "ù"], ["a'", "e'", "e'", "i", "o'", "u'"], $res_to_write);
$resfile = iconv("UTF-8", "US-ASCII//TRANSLIT", $res_to_write);
```